# Are there measures in place by Google to prevent malicious Places API abuse?

Tags: android, google-maps, security, google-cloud-platform, google-places-api

I have an Android app in which the Places AutoComplete API is used. Now, Google charges $x/request so I'm thinking to put in some measures in my app so that someone with malicious intents does not build some sort of `(Enter Search term -> Click -> Dismiss -> Repeat)` kind of robot or mechanical contraption as done by cheats in for example the [clash of clans game](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pxn9p_Yqg2U).

My approach would be to either limit search and click count to x per day. Or to detect when constant search and click is taking place. If I don't do this and someone search clicks a million times a day then I'm the one who pays at the end of the day.

**But before I do that, does Google have measures in place** to detect this sort of constant request response attack and therefore restrict usage in some way?

**Note:** to use the app's search feature (and others) one must subscribe (pay per month). I could switch to a consumable model where they pay once and get e.g 1000 searches etc; But this question is not around that. The [Places API requires search feature to include attribution](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/policies) therefore those that know will know there is an underlying Google API that they can abuse. Owner of the key is the one that will pay, and I do not want to find myself with a ridiculous bill caused by a `hacker`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google does provide some preventive measures you can implement to secure your API key and control your API usage and associated costs.

(a) Assuming you use the Places SDK for Android, [restrict](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/get-api-key#restrict-key) your API key to your package name and fingerprint to prevent third-party unauthorized use and quota theft.

(b) Set daily quota limits and budget alerts to cap your API usage within your budget. Check out [this FAQ](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#usage_cap).

Hope this helps!

Comment: It is! :) Just make sure you set a reasonable limit, otherwise if the APIs reach the limit within a given day, they will stop working until the quota is reset the next day.